# Jquery toggle() not working on YouTube subscription button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

Want to create a **DIV which toggle when I click on *youtube* subscription button**. Also, I want to hide the Youtube button.
This seems easy, but **Jquery** toggle method is not working on youtube sub button.

### CODE ↓

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(e){
//Your code here
    $('#xx2').click(){
    $('#cc').toggle();
    }
});
</script>


<div id="cc" style="display:none;" >
    <h1>this is a hidden item</h1>
</div>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>
<div id="btn">
<div id="xx2" class="g-ytsubscribe" 
data-channelid="UCwevqbHI8ppBSvVKESoLpPQ" 
data-layout="full" data-count="default" ></div>
</div>
```

See this photograph :[image]

Comment: Would you mind to remove the horizontal scollbar, by reformating your source code?

Comment: help me guys, can't understand what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Please close the script tag and provide some text inside the xx2 div.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e){
    $('#xx2').click(function(e){
        $('#cc').toggle();
    });
});
</script>
<div id="cc" style="display:none;">
    <h1>this is a hidden item</h1>
</div>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>
<div id="btn">
<div id="xx2" class="g-ytsubscribe" 
data-channelid="UCwevqbHI8ppBSvVKESoLpPQ" 
data-layout="full" data-count="default" >text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Syntax error**

1. Change `$(document)` instead of `$("document")`
2. And `click` function declaration was wrong. initiate the click `function` of `xx2` and the toggle inside the click function

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $('#xx2').click(function() {
    $('#cc').toggle();
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cc" style="display:none;">
  <h1>this is a hidden item</h1>
</div>
<div id="btn">
  <div id="xx2" class="g-ytsubscribe" data-channelid="UCwevqbHI8ppBSvVKESoLpPQ" data-layout="full" data-count="default">xx</div>
</div>
```

Comment: i have added a picture, please see that

Answer (score 0):

there is error in the syntax of jquery, use following cod:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(e){
        $('#xx2').click(function(){
            $('#cc').toggle();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: still not working... actually,  i want to hide that div("#CC"). when someone clicks on youtube subscription button

Comment: use $('#cc').css('display','none'); instead of $('#cc').toggle();

Comment: added a picture,please see that first

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the classic way will work:

HTML:

```
<div id="cc">
    <h1>this is a hidden item</h1>
</div>
<div id="btn">
  <div id="xx2" class="g-ytsubscribe"
      data-channelid="UCwevqbHI8ppBSvVKESoLpPQ" 
      data-layout="full" data-count="default">
         xxx <!-- The xxx is used for better hitting -->
    </div>
</div>
```

I removed the style attribute from `#cc`.
Added following CSS:

```
div.cc {display:none;}
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#xx2').click(function() {
        $('#cc').toggleClass("cc");
    });
});
```

So far I understand your problem right, this did work according Jsfiddle.net .